# MATLAB-style gradient for R's optimx

Tags: r, performance, optimization

I use R `optimx` in order to optimize my function. In MATLAB I always write:

```
function[f,g] = calculations(x,otherParameters)
% some calculations
f=someting
g=somethingOther
% Here f and g are function and gradient values that fmincon use for optimization
```

So then both `f` and `g` values are provided to `fmincon`. But when I use `optimx` I should provide gradient function separately. The disadvantage of this requirement is that I have many values calculated for f that then are need to estimate g. So making separate function for gradient force me to calculate some values twice that is computationally inefficient. Please help me understand how to avoid this problem in R in the most efficient way (for example making global variables seems to me not a very good approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nloptr package allows one to return the objective function and gradient as a two component list.  See the example in the vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/vignettes/nloptr.pdf as repeated here:

```
library(nloptr)

eval_f_list <- function(x) {
  common <- x[2] - x[1] * x[1]
  return( list(objective = 100 * common^2 + (1 - x[1])^2,
               gradient = c(-400 * x[1] * common - 2 * (1 - x[1]), 200 * common)))
}
x0 <- c( -1.2, 1 )
opts <- list("algorithm" = "NLOPT_LD_LBFGS", "xtol_rel" = 1.0e-8)

res <- nloptr( x0=x0, eval_f=eval_f_list, opts=opts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `memoise` package. To explain in more detail, consider the trivial example of how you might optimise in R for a function where you know the dervivative:

```
complex.function <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(3)
}

f <- function(x){
  cat("f",x,"\n")
  complex.function(x)
  (x-1)^4+(x-1)^2+7
}

g <- function(x){
  cat("g",x,"\n")
  complex.function(x)
  4*(x-1)^3+2*(x-1)
}

system.time(optim(3.1, f, g,method="BFGS")) ##57.01sec
#f 3.1 
#g 3.1 
#f -38.144 
#f -5.1488 
#f 1.45024 
#g 1.45024 
#f 1.398015 
#g 1.398015 
#f 1.146116 
#g 1.146116 
#f 0.8414061 
#f 1.085174 
#g 1.085174 
#f 1.00532 
#g 1.00532 
#f 1.000081 
#g 1.000081 
#f 0.9999192 
#f 1.000048
```

Because the method evaluates f and g at mostly the same points, there is the potential for optimisation.

Now, if you `memoise()` the function with the complex calculations in, it caches the output, so you can do something like:

```
library(memoise)

complex.function2 <- memoise(function(x){
  Sys.sleep(3)
  list(fun=(x-1)^4+(x-1)^2+7,deriv=4*(x-1)^3+2*(x-1))
})



f2 <- function(x){
  cat("f2",x,"\n")
  complex.function2(x)$fun
}

g2 <- function(x){
  cat("g2",x,"\n")
  complex.function2(x)$deriv
}

system.time(optim(3.1, f2, g2,method="BFGS")) ##36.02sec
```

and cut the number of times that the complex function is called, and hence the execution time on my computer falls from 57 to 36 seconds.

Check the help file for `optim` to see whether the method you're interested in using actually uses the derivatives - if not, all this is a moot point.